# Attribute Matching

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here is the scenario:

I have two tables I need to compare attributes in the following table:

Attribute Table

```
Code | part_number | brand | View_all
```

Attribute Details

```
AttriID| Name | LongName | ShortName
1 | Price| price_1 | pri   
2 | Path | path_1 | pat  
3 | Code_No | Code_Number| Code
```

I need to take the Attribute table to go column by column and look into the Attribute details table in Name column, I need to check if there best match in the Name column.

For example: take code attribute and from Attribute table and see the best match for code in the name column in the Attribute details table. I need to develop this application in C# .NET.

Thank you!

c#

Comment: What code do you have so far? Are you using an ORM or are you writing SQL by hand?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make this much clearer.  For instance, what are you comparing the `name` column to?